# Should I center a headline written in Traditional Chinese?

Tags: traditional-characters

I'm putting together an email campaign and have a headline in Traditional Chinese. In terms of formatting, is it acceptable to center the headline? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we always do that in email.